# How to draw contour plot with three.js

Tags: three.js, heatmap, projection, contour

Like this example here: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo2.hires.png

How can I draw the contour plot for the 3d surface object?

In the same time, on vertical plane, how can I draw the objection?

Comment: @Lee Stemkoski should be able to help out with this. Check out his amazing [math related three.js](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/) contributions, especially the [function grapher](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Function.html). In terms of projection to planes, a very hacky option might be to clone the 3d mesh, flatten it (set a very small scale on one dimmension) to get a projection, but it would be nicer to traverse the generated mesh and draw a curve per division

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeProfenza! I did exactly the same thing for vertical projection. It's a good idea to traverse the mesh and draw curves, I'm going to test this.

Comment: Good luck! I'd also recommend having a small distance between the flat 2 plots to avoid z-fighting.